# What's the significance of the 2 periods here "../bin/python"

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to do the quick installation described [here](https://github.com/plumi/plumi.app/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.rst).

One of the instructions is to run

```
~/plumi.app/ffmpeg$../bin/python bootstrap.py && ./bin/buildout -vN
```

There are 2 periods before the first /bin and there's one period before the second `/bin`.

I'm wondering if this is a typo, because a little before that, there's an instruction as follows:

```
~/plumi.app$./bin/python bootstrap.py && ./bin/buildout -v
```

And in this case, there's only one period before each `/bin`.

Also, I understand that `./bin/python` is the same thing as `bin/python` but does Ubuntu Linux Server correctly interpret `./bin/python`?

Comment: Nothing about Python, but about paths in general; see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/absolute-and-relative-paths-256350/ etc. (Note that `~` is expanded before the path is handed to the OS, but `.` and `..` are OS/FS-level constructs.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One period (`.`) means this directory. Two periods (`..`) mean the parent directory.

This is not a typo in the instructions. The first command is executed from the directory `~/plumi.app`, so the path to `~/plumi.app/bin/python` can be given using any of the following:

- `~/plumi.app/bin/python`
- `./bin/python`
- `bin/python`

After moving to `~/plumi.app/ffmpeg` using the command `cd ffmpeg`, the path can be given using

- `~/plumi.app/bin/python`
- `../bin/python`
- `~/plumi.app/ffmpeg/../bin/python`

The last one is a bit pointless, but shows that `..` can be used anywhere in the path to refer to a directory's parent.

Comment: tom, thanks - quick follow-up. In the instruction "~/plumi.app/ffmpeg$../bin/python bootstrap.py && ./bin/buildout -vN" , the second /bin with the single period before it, where is it located, in ffmpeg or in plumi.app? Also, will Ubuntu Linux Server interpret it correctly or should I write it as "~/plumi.app/ffmpeg$../bin/python bootstrap.py && bin/buildout -vN" (i.e., without the ./ in front of the bin/buildout). Thanks.

Comment: The second is located in `~/plumi.app/ffmpeg`. Ubuntu Server will interpret it correctly assuming you don't type in the prompt (`~/plumi.app/ffmpeg$`), which is never meant to be typed in.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a typo. In all Unix-like OSs, `.` is a directory's name for itself, while `..` is its name for its parent directory.

So in your first command, `../bin/python` says "look to the parent directory of the current directory, then look into a `bin` directory it holds, then run the `python` file you find there".

In the second command you quoted, the current directory is different (one level higher). This means that the `..` isn't necessary, since you're already in the directory that the previous `..` indicated.

Answer (score 1):

The `..` means "go back one directory", so it looks one directory out.

In this case it does seem to be a typo.

---

The reason for `./foo` instead of `foo` is because the shell can't tell that `foo` is a path, so thinks it's a command.

In the case of `./foo/bar`, the `./` is *not* needed because the shell can tell. It is left because it's traditional, I guess.